# Uncrowded budget ski resort in the Alps with children which is also good to spend time for non-skiers

Tags: sightseeing, children, alps, skiing, resorts

We are looking for a skiing resort in Alps to visit in first half of March 2014.

Which of them is at the same time uncrowded for mid- and advanced-level skiers, while has enough facilities for non-sporty non-skiers to spend 10-14 days on/close to the resort?

For non-skiers, we are looking for enough space for walk and sightseeing; public playgrounds and water parks / swimming pools; picturesque sights (Chamonix and Mayerhofen are good examples), with little to no driving required (Canazei is counter-example: the village small itself; long driving required for every trip to overcome a mountain pass to reach sightseeing destinations). Ideally to have option to spend some time in the mountains, eg. in restaurants at 1st level of ski lifts (accessible without ski).

For skiers, we need a couple of black pistes, some for 5-6 year old children riding with parents (not with a ski school), wide choice for mid-level skiers.

Answer (score 9):

[Innsbruck](http://www.innsbruck.info/en/home.html), the capital of Tyrol, offers everything you are looking for. The city itself offers a lot of activities. There are ski resorts directly accessible from the city center accessible by cable car. Otherwise there are shuttle buses to nearby areas such as Axamer Lizum, Schlick 2000 and a bit further the Stubaier Gletscher.

[Garmisch-Partenkirchen](http://www.gapa.de), in Bavaria, can be a good choice too. The ski resorts can be reached by cable car, which makes them easily accessible for pedestrians. Munich, as well as the famous world heritage castles are just one hour away.

As an alternative to Garmisch, you can also choose to stay at the Tyrolean side, the so-called, "[Zugspitz Arena](http://www.zugspitzarena.com)", a very family friendly place.

[Faistenau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/are-the-ski-runs-easily-connected-to-the-salzburg-airport-and-city) is a cozy village near Salzburg. It has an alpine ski resort. There are more resorts in the area. And you are only 30 minutes from Salzburg, a fine destination for sightseeing.